# How can I check whether phone number exists in a db during file import?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to check if the phone exists or not in the database. If it exists, the row should be skipped. Can I do this without calling the database every time?

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Friend;
use App\Traits\UniqueId;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class FriendsImport implements ToModel, WithBatchInserts, WithHeadingRow
{
    use UniqueId;

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Friend([
            'phone' => $row['phone'],
            'postcode' => $row['postcode'],
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'unique_id' => $this->generateUniqueNumber(),
        ]);
    }

    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways to "solve" what you want, that doesn't mean this ways are performant... One would be to store the numbers in a `cache` like [tag:redis] so it is accessible super fast (this would be the best one). Another process would be send the file a `job` (asynchronous) and let it ask row by row for the number and then call the DB and remove the row if it exists. Once the `job` finished, send it to another `job` that will handle adding the rows to your table because the file already does not have the existing phones... It is really opinion-based, so...

Comment: @matiaslauriti Sure, there are a lot of ways to do it, but OP isn't asking for the best way, only *how* to do it. That doesn't make this question opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

You can check like this.

```
    $validator = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($row,['phone'=>'require|unique:friends,phone']);
    if ($validator->passes()){
        // Phone number does not exist on the friends table.
    }else{
        // Phone number exist on the friends table.
    }
```

If you want to check the existence in the same chunk (batch), you need to save all batch data in static value

like

```php
// Import class

public static $chunkFriends = [];


// in them model function, for each row

array_push (self::chunkFriends, $row);
```

Then you need to clear $chunkFriends in the each chunk read event.

```
public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return [
        ReadChunk::class=> function(){
            // put a code here
            self::chunkFriends = [];
        }
    ];
}
```

Another solution is to use Session or Cache driver.

Comment: Get error after 

public static chunkFriends = []; syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: sorry, I missed $ symbol. 
public static $chunkFriends = [];

Answer (score 1):

First, you can do unique the phones before you insert them into database.

Or, You can use the eloquent to do it.

You can use the FirstOrCreate method.

This method insert a new record when the identity key not found, else return row found.

Can see it: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models